# Mathematica 10.2 break downs when `StreamPlot`-ing

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 12.0 or earlier**

---

This code meets error:

```
 f[{v1_, v2_}, {x_, y_}] := 
     StreamPlot[
      Evaluate[{v1/(1 + x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), v2/(1 + x^2 + y^2)^(
         3/2)} /. {x -> u/Sqrt[1 - u^2 - v^2], 
         y -> v/Sqrt[1 - u^2 - v^2]}], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
 f[{2 x y, 1 + y - x^2 + y^2}, {x, y}]
```

[image]

(I notice that this error sometimes but not alaways happens,but when you run it again and again for many times,i.e. 3 times the error comes.)

while this code doesn't:

```
f[{v1_, v2_}, {x_, y_}] := 
 StreamPlot[
  Evaluate[{v1/(1 + x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), v2/(1 + x^2 + y^2)^(
     3/2)} /. {x -> u/Sqrt[1 - u^2 + v^2], 
     y -> v/Sqrt[1 - u^2 + v^2]}], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
f[{2 x y, 1 + y - x^2 + y^2}, {x, y}]
```

So what on earth happens?

Comment: 1) what is the difference between the two code fragments? 2) Could you provide an English translation of your error?

Comment: @MarcoB the difference is in the normalization of x and y. In the first version, they are divided by `Sqrt[1 - u^2 - v^2]`, in the second version `Sqrt[1 - u^2 + v^2]`, and, yes, I had to look very closely as well. I presume he's seeing a kernel crash.

Comment: What version of _Mathematica_ are you using?

Comment: @MarcoB 1) The difference is the sign in the rule 2)The error window tells us that kernel breaks down---just similar to that in my previous question e.g,http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88862/mma-breaks-down-when-dsolve-ing-a-third-order-linear-ode.

Comment: @rcollyer I have told you in my tiltle.

Comment: maybe I should learn to read. :P

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in V12.0 and have updated the header accordingly. If someone can test an earlier version, they could make the header more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Surd` instead of `Sqrt`.

```
f[{v1_, v2_}, {x_, y_}] := 
StreamPlot[Evaluate[{v1/(1 + x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), 
v2/(1 + x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)} /. {x -> u/Surd[1 - u^2 - v^2, 2], 
y -> v/Surd[1 - u^2 - v^2, 2]}], {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
f[{2 x y, 1 + y - x^2 + y^2}, {x, y}] // Quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

**The below explanation is fairly plausible, but either way the answer is to build up the data in a table and `ListStreamPlot` it**

I had a similar problem with `StreamPlot[{1, Sqrt[1 - x^2] Cos[y + 1]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`.

My conjecture is that since streamlines require numerically integrating the field, fields that are hard to integrate (require small step size) take too long and the plotter crashes. The above code runs fine on my machine when I only take `x` to `0.1`. `NDSolve`ing the associated ODE shows the default number of steps becomes insufficient somewhere in the middle.